# Setting DNS for Github Pages

Tags: domain-name-system, github

I am attempting to direct a top level domain to a site hosted by Github pages.

The documentation can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) but it is unclear to me what to set the `Host` to in my `A record`.

And on that note, what is the functional purpose of the `Host` within a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Host Record is the same thing as an A Record. The A Record (Host Record) allows you to point different "hosts" on your domain to different IP addresses.

I.e

```
example.com               A     101.1.1.1
server1.example.com       A     101.1.1.2
server2.example.com       A     101.1.1.3
```

So, in other words, the A record just allows you to setup different IP addresses to different subdomains on your parent domain.

Answer (score 1):

You would just point

```
domain.com -> 204.232.175.78
www.domain.com -> 204.232.175.78
```

both of those owuld be A records in your dns tool.

or you can do

```
www.domain.com -> domain.com
```

with a CNAME alias

Comment: so `domain.com` is what I set as my `Host`?

Comment: ya.. host can be anything.. you might want to move domain.com or code.domain.com